# NSMutableSet addObject

Tags: objective-c, foundation

I've got a class that wraps around an `NSMutableSet` object, and I have an instance method that adds objects (using the `addObject:` method) to the `NSMutableSet`.

This works well, but I'm smelling a performance hitch because inside the method i'm explicitly calling `containsObject:` before adding the object to the set.

Three part question:

1. Do I need to be calling `containsObject:` before I add an object to the set?
2. If so, then what actual method should I be using, `containsObject` or `containsObjectIdenticalTo:`?
3. If that is not so, what `contains` method gets invoked under the hood of `addObject:`?  This is important to me because if I pass an object to `containsObject:` it would return true, but if I pass it to `containsObjectIdenticalTo:` it would return false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're wrapping an `NSMutableSet`, then invoking `containsObject:` is unnecessary, since a set ([by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(computer_science))) does not contain duplicates.  As such, if you attempt to insert an object that is already in the set, nothing will happen.

As far as a performance hit goes, don't worry about it unless you actually measure it being an issue.  I'd be very very very surprised if you even could, because a set (at least, a smart implementation of a set) has O(1) lookup time (average case).  I guarantee you that `NSSet` and friends are smart implementations. :)

From what I've gathered about the implementation of `NSSet`, it's invoking `-hash` on the objects as a way to "group" them into bins if you use `containsObject:` or `addObject:`.  If you use `containsObjectIdenticalTo:`, it'll still use `-hash` to narrow down the search process, and then (essentially) do pointer comparisons to find the identical object.